# How to change icon of item by using QStyledItemDelegate for custom QItemlist depends on condition?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I build a QListwidget with custom itemwidget this list. The idea I want to change the icon of the item depends on condition. I read about the MVC model, but I couldn't know how to built QStyledItemDelegate to update them.

Now, I delete all items in the list and read them, that works if the list small but when I have a lot of item it takes time.

This code of CostmItemWidget:

```
class CustomQWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, file, parent=None):
        super(CustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        if file["l_file"]:
            pathname = os.path.join(parent.parent.main_script_path, "icons/correct.png")
        else:
            pathname = os.path.join(parent.parent.main_script_path, "icons/wrong.png")
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pathname)
        button = QPushButton()
        button.setStyleSheet("padding: 0px;")
        button.setFixedSize(16, 16)

        # resize pixmap
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(button.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        cropOffsetX = (pixmap.width() - button.size().width()) / 2
        pixmap = pixmap.copy(cropOffsetX, 0, button.size().width(), button.size().height())

        button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(pixmap))
        button.setIconSize(button.size())
        button.setFlat(True)
        label = QLabel(file["n_file"])
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button, 0)
        layout.addWidget(label, 0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

And this code of widget content list:

```
class FileListWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        loadUi(os.path.join(".", "UIFiles", 'filelist_widget.ui'), self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.refresh_list()
        self.list_view.setCurrentRow(0)
        self.list_view.itemClicked.connect(self.selected_file)
        self.list_view.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item { padding: 0px; }")

    def refresh_list(self):
        self.list_view.clear()
        if len(self.parent.files) == 0:
            return
        for index, file in self.parent.files.iterrows():
            self.add_item_list(file)
        self.parent.image_deleted = False

    def add_item_list(self, file):
        item = QListWidgetItem(self.list_view)
        item.setSizeHint(QSize(item.sizeHint().width(), 20))
        item_widget2 = CustomQWidget(file, self)
        self.list_view.addItem(item)
        self.list_view.setItemWidget(item, item_widget2)
```

I looking to find a way of applying QStyledItemDelegate and change the icon by a certain signal. The icon of the button in the CustomQWidget and I want to change it when the value of "l_file" from the dictionary is True.

This image of the list I have

[image]

Comment: What icon do you mean? And when do you want to change the icon ?, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I update the question, and the icon I meant is in the CustomWidget and I would update it when ```file["l_file] == True```. That value will change when the user changes the selected file from the list.

Answer (score 0):

I created this delegate to handle put icon inside the custom Widget of the QListItemWidget.

```
class FileListDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
def __init__(self, parent, list_view):
    super(FileListDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
    # pointer to list
    self.list_view = list_view

def paint(self, painter: QtGui.QPainter, option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> None:
    painter.save()
    item = self.list_view.itemFromIndex(index)
    widget = self.list_view.itemWidget(item)
    layout = widget.layout()
    button = layout.itemAt(0).widget()
    if self.list_view.parent().parent().parent.files.loc[widget.index, 'l_file']:
        pathname = os.path.join(widget.main_script_path, "icons/correct.png")
    else:
        pathname = os.path.join(widget.main_script_path, "icons/wrong.png")
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pathname)
    button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(pixmap))
    button.setIconSize(button.size())
    painter.restore()
```